# MasterCard Sample Code Sample_REST-JSON_PHP error Invalid MerchantID

Tags: php, gateway, mastercard

I am asking for help on an error I got when I try to integrate the MasterCard Payment Gateway Sample Code:
Gateway sample code link: https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/downloads/example/Sample_REST-JSON_PHP.zip?locale=en_US

I configure the following field in the configuration.php

```
// Base URL of the Payment Gateway. Do not include the version.
$configArray["gatewayUrl"] = "https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/";

// Merchant ID supplied by your payments provider
$configArray["merchantId"] = "[INSERT-MERCHANT-ID]";

// API username in the format below where Merchant ID is the same as above
$configArray["apiUsername"] = "merchant.[INSERT-MERCHANT-ID]";

// API password which can be configured in Merchant Administration
$configArray["password"] = "";
```

I am pretty sure my Merchant ID, which is provided by a financial provider, is correct.  However, I got the following error, could you please help to advise? Thanks.

```
{
    "error": {
        "cause": "INVALID_REQUEST",
        "explanation": "Value '[INSERT-MERCHANT-ID]' is invalid. No valid Merchant Acquirer Relationship available",
        "field": "merchantId",
        "validationType": "INVALID"
    },
    "result": "ERROR"
}
```

Regards,
Carlos

Answer (score 0):

You need the `merchantId` from a payment service provider. It says as much in the error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I get the merchantID from my financial provider.  I get the error.  If I place others such ads 'TESTABCDEF'.   It will be invalid response error instead of invalid merchantID error.

Comment: Can you share more details of the request you're sending to MPGS with the new `merchantId` @TechWiFi

Comment: I got the merchantId from the financial provider before the post.  After you reminded me, I check again with the financial provider if the merchantid is valid or not and they are currently checking.  The error code remained "Value '[INSERT-MERCHANT-ID]' is invalid. No valid Merchant Acquirer Relationship available"  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I found the root cause and the issue solved.  The merchantid is correct.  The error is caused by incorrect currency code.  Each merchantid is only related to certain currency.  Thanks  ザヘド for your help.

Comment: Without seeing the request being sent, it was not possible to know what could have gone wrong. Glad that you were able to resolve it

Comment: Thanks ザヘド again.  Actually your answer gives me a lot of hints.  The merchantID is actually not correct for the currency I used before.  After you provided the hints, I confirmed it is the issue of the merchantID setting and ask the financial provider again.

Comment: Hi, hope all is well. I am currently using firebase as my backend and im starting the integration process with MPGS, will i be able to accomplish it with firebase or will i be to have a nodeJS express server to do that for me?